# mysql - update date field if exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have query that save the reservation number that user watch. the system always display the last 10 reservation per user (sort by "createDate" column), so if some reservation number is already in the last 10 the query don't do anything.

I would like to change it a little bit and if the reservation number is already in the table than to update the field "createDate" with the current date and time.
If not exist than insert new row.

What should i change?

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO user_last_view
            (userID,
             page,
             refid,
             mode) 
           SELECT ".$_SESSION['userDetails']['userID'].",
                  '".$page."',
                  ".$refID.", 
                  '".$mode."'
                  FROM dual
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                           FROM (SELECT ulv.userID,
                                                        ulv.page,
                                                        ulv.refid
                                                        FROM user_last_view ulv
                                                        ORDER BY ulv.createdate
                                                        DESC LIMIT 10) x
                                           WHERE x.userID = ".$_SESSION['userDetails']['userID']."
                                                 AND x.page = '".$page."'
                                                 AND x.refid = ".$refID.");
";

$conn->query($query);
```

Comment: I would say you should have a second column called "modifiedDate" - it's going to get confusing later on if your "createDate" column might be the date the row was created, or might be the date it was modified. I believe there's a way for mysql to automatically update a last-modified date, similar to how it can automatically populate the "created" date, using "ON UPDATE".

Comment: Do you really want to update the row date when the row IS DISPLAYED to user?